# Armature Winding

Tags: power, motor, power-electronics, electromagnetism, electric-machine

[image]

This might seem like a silly question, buy why aren't armature windings usually done in a simple manner as shown in the image, why does it have to be more complicated such as lap winding etc?

Answer (score 1):

> *why aren't armature windings usually done in a simple manner....*

[image]

If you had one armature winding with two commutator segments (as per the above picture), the motor might not spin at all when the coil was vertical but, if it did spin, it would have a very high ripple torque making it unsuitable for many applications. This is why we have many commutator segments and windings in a DC motor: -

[image]

Images from [here](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/index.php/Brushed_DC_Motor_Theory).

If the single armature winding motor was energized, it would likely halt as per the right hand image above. So, we add more armature windings and commutator segments to ensure that there is always one winding that is producing torque to keep the motor spinning.

[image]

And clearly, if we add more windings and commutator segments we can produce a smoother torque delivery to the load. Think of an old cassette deck; if the motor torque were "ripply" the music playback would also be speed modulated and produce a wobbled sound.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I didn't mean why there's only one loop. In a lap wound or wave wound armature, each commutator segment would have two loops attached to it, unlike in the image. Why is that? Is it because the current has a longer path to flow? Or is it something else? That's my question